# $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = M$ and $\sup_{[0,1]}(f) = M \implies f(x)=M$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $[0, 1]$, such that $\sup_{[0,1]}(f) = M$. Assume $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = M$. Prove that $f(x) = M $ on  $[0; 1].$ Also if the $\sup_{[0,2]}(f) = M$ we get $\int_0^2 f(x)dx = 2M$.

I tried everything , I cant seem to solve it.

Comment: Define the partition $P_n=\{0,\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},\dots,1\}$ of $[0,1]$. Now look at the upper Darboux sum according to $P_n$.

Comment: You can simplify matters a tad by showing that the the function $g=M-f$ is identically $0$.  Note $g$ is nonnegative and $\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $f(x) = M$ on $[0,1]$ is not true. Now this along with the fact that $\sup_{[0,1]}f = M$, gives us that $f(y) = M-\epsilon$ for some $y \in [0,1]$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f(x)$ is continuous, there exists a $\delta > 0$, such that for all $x \in E_{\delta} = (y -\delta,y + \delta)$, we have $$f(x) \in \left(M - 3 \epsilon/2, M-\epsilon/2\right)$$ Now $$\int_{[0,1]} f(x) dx = \int_{E_{\delta}} f(x) dx + \int_{[0,1] \backslash E_{\delta}} f(x) dx$$
Now $$\int_{E_{\delta}} f(x) dx < (M-\epsilon/2) 2 \delta$$ and $$\int_{[0,1] \backslash E_{\delta}} f(x) dx < M(1- 2\delta)$$
Hence, we get that $$M = \int_{[0,1]} f(x) dx < M- \epsilon \delta < M$$ which is a contradiction. Hence, $f(x) = M$ on $[0,1]$. The same argument works for the interval $[0,2]$.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Assume $f(x_0)\ne M$ for some $x_0$. Then $f(x)<\frac{f(x_0)+M}2$ on an interval around $x_0$, thus making $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$ definitely $<M$.

For the second part, you don't *get* $\int_0^2f(x)\,dx=2M$, you get that $f$ is constant if you this time *assume* that $\int_0^2f(x)\,dx=2M$.

Comment: Are you sure about the second part. I think the way i asked the question is not clear, in the second part $\sup_{[0,1]}(f) \not= M$ but your reasoning works also on the second part

Comment: Yes, if $f$ is continuous on $[0,2]$ and $\sup_{[0,2]} f=M$, we do not *get* that $\int_0^2f(x)\, dx=2M$ as can be seen by considering $f(x)=M-x$.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of your question:
$$
0=M-\int_0^1f(x)dx=\int_0^1(M-f(x))dx.
$$
Now observe that the function $g(x):=M-f(x)$ is continuous and non-negative on $[0,1]$.
Since its integral on $[0,1]$ is equal to $0$, the function $g$ must be constant equal to $0$ on $[0,1]$.